# Windows API reference for OllyDbg

Tags: winapi, ollydbg

There is an old help file containing Windows API I used few years ago with ollydebug, which can jump to the appropriate help page of function when double clicking on the function in the disassembly window.

Is there a more recent reference like this which includes also Windows 7 library calls ?

I managed to find an online reference in Microsoft website but a local file is much easier to work with...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using OllyDbg 1.x, you could use the [MSDN Help Plugin](http://blog.buguroo.com/?p=4071&lang=en) which simply looks up the requested API call on MSDN. It works for me on my Windows XP sp3 system with OllyDbg 1.x.

Of course, this requires internet connectivity.

Another incomplete option that *may* work is to obtain the Windows 7 SDK and be sure to install the "Documentation / Win32 and COM" sub feature.

Then copy all the *.HXS files from the SDK install folder. Then the only task left is to find a way to convert *.HXS files into a single *.HLP file....not sure if that's possible or not.

FWIW, the [IDA Scope](https://bitbucket.org/daniel_plohmann/simplifire.idascope) plugin (for IDA Pro) recommends this in their [manual](http://pnx-tf.blogspot.com/2012/07/idascope-update-winapi-browsing.html) for integrating offline MSDN help. Except their instructions have the user extract the HXS files to a folder and point IDA Scope to it where IDA Scope knows how to read/parse the files extracted from the HXS files. The HXS files can be deleted after extracting.

Comment: MSDN plugin is an excellent solution for me, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Is this something You looking for?

[Win32api and x86 Opcodes](http://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.3307)

Comment: Not up-to-date, though. And wouldn't be. But the new help systems also would allow for integration, probably the OllyDbg author simply hasn't done it.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend installing the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717422.aspx) documentation and the [Driver Development Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11800) if you don't have them already. It might seem like overkill but it's extremely helpful to have both of these documentation kits locally.

A word of caution when installing the Windows SDK documentation. Microsoft removed dexplore.exe (viewer) in the Windows 7 2010 SDK update. It now relies on the default browser and the documentation has to be pre-configured and downloaded. The new viewing option feels much slower than dexplorer.exe. I have the Windows XP SDK and the Windows 7 SDK documentation installed because I prefer dexplorer.exe